# $A = \{x+ 1/n : x \in (0,1), n \in \mathbb Z^+ \}.$ Determine the supremum and infimum of $A$, if they exist.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A =\{x+ 1/n : x \in (0,1), n \in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Determine the supremum and infimum of $A$, if they  exist.
Rigorously justify your answers

Comment: Okay, I have just determined the supremum and infimum. What else?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch great comment

Comment: Thinking about the supremum, have you considered what happens when x = 1 and n = 1?  Do you think the infimum is less than zero, equal to zero or more than zero?

Comment: I understand there is an upper bound of 2 and lower bound at 0 but it is proving its the least upper bound and greatest lower bound I can't do @MilesB

Comment: The title says $Z^+$ but in the body of your post it just says $Z$.  I assume n can only be a positive integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a \in A$ then $ \exists x \in (0,1)$ and $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $a = x+1/n$. As $x<1$ and $n \geq 1$, $a < 2$ so 2 is an upper bound.

To show 2 is the least upper bound, then suppose $\exists m$ such that $0 < m < 2$ and $m$ is an upper bound. $0 < m/2 < 1$. Therefore, $a = m/2+1/1 \in A$, but $m/2+1/1 = m/2+1 > m/2 + m/2 = m$ so $a>m$ and $m$ cannot be an upper bound.

To show 0 is the greatest lower bound, suppose $\exists m$ such that $0 < m < 1$ and $m$ is a lower bound.  Now simply set $x=m/2$ and $n$ to be an integer greater than $2/m$.  Then $a = x+1/n < m/2+1/(2/m) = m/2 + m/2 = m$.  So $a<m$ but $a \in A$ so m cannot be a lower bound of A.